# Borel measure $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}$ so that the induced measure has covariance but no mean

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Kuo's book, he says if $\mu$ is a Borel measure in $\mathbb{R}$ with

$$\int_\mathbb{R} x ~\mu(dx) =\infty,\quad \int_\mathbb{R} x ^2 \mu(dx) <\infty.$$

Then the directional measure, defined by
$$\mu_e(A)=\mu(\zeta(A\cap [e]))$$
with $\zeta:[e]\to \mathbb{R},\zeta(a\cdot v)=a$ has no mean operator but a covariance operator. I see why that would follow but cannot construct such a $\mu$.

I tried to find a borel measurable $f$ such that $\mu\sim f dx$ but couldnt.
Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu(dx)=e^{-|x|}/|x|^2 \,dx$, maybe?  Or, if you like, $\mu(dx) = x^{-2} dx$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ otherwise.  Which has infinite total mass, infinite first moment, but finite second moment.

Comment: The $\text{Ei}$ function has a singularity at $0$; the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}/xdx$ is not finite.